# ACCESS 2007 Join statement

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am not sure how to write this join statement.  I tried it a few different ways with various errors.

I get the error "ODBC--connection to 'MYCONN' failed."

```
SELECT ad.ad_addr
FROM 
    PUB_cm_mstr AS cm 
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        PUB_ad_mstr AS ad 
        INNER JOIN 
        PUB_BusinessRelation AS br 
            ON ad.ad_ref = br.BusinessRelationCode
    ) 
        ON cm.cm_addr = br.BusinessRelationName2;
```

Comment: There's no reference to MYCONN in that string.  Perhaps MYCONN isn't set up properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution which i did not love was to have two sources and then merge join them together to get the information I needed.